# How to add unsubscribe link in all the emails in magneto 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to add unsubscribe link in footer of all my email templates such as order confirmation, order delivered, order cancelled.

I tried all the solutions from the internet. but nothing works fine.

How can i add unsubscription link to all my email templates?

Comment: add ing footer template it will reflect in all email templates

Comment: HI @WaqarAli, how can i add that variable in footer.

Comment: check this https://bsscommerce.com/blog/customize-magento-2-footer-template/